# numPy gives nan while reading a negative number from a file

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I tried to read the contents of a 3x3 matrix stored in a text file having the following values.

```
−30  10  20  
 10  40 −50  
 20 −50 −10
```

I used `numpy.genfromtxt` as follows but when it gave `nan` in place of negative data values.

```
data = np.genfromtxt('file.txt',delimiter=' ')
print(data)
print(type(data[0][0]))
```

But the datatype of the negative value still shows `float64`:

[image: The screenshot of code and output.]

I also tried reading the values as a list and then converting to numpy array but that also didn't work.

Is there any other way I can read negative values as a numpy array from a file input?

Comment: Please do not post text such as code, error messages, or data on SO, always post the text directly here on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got U+2212 MINUS SIGN characters in your file, not the U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS people usually think of as the minus sign character. `genfromtxt` doesn't handle that character. Replace the minus sign characters with hyphen-minuses before trying to parse the data.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for the answer. I didn't know about this convention.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead:

```
data=pd.read_csv("data.txt",delimiter=",")
data = DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: I tried it and it works, you give me -1 without even try it ?

Comment: You don't know who downvoted your answer, so don't blame the OP. In fact, it is rather unlikely that it was the OP.

Comment: I guess you got down vote because the OP's input data are NOT **comma** (`,`) delimited .