# invalid character in identifier in python 3 in a Jupyter notebook, arrow pointing to a negative sign. Can I not have a negative in my list?

Tags: python, jupyter

I am trying to find the mean of a list. I believe the negative number in the beginning of my list is somehow throwing me for a loop.
Please show me the proper way to find the mean of this simple list.

```
B = [−5,3,12,190,−10]

print(np.mean(B))

#OUTPUT:

File "<ipython-input-35-5b44dec66063>", line 1
    B = [−5,3,12,190,−10]
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Comment: Thats not a valid negative sign. Use the key next to your 0 on your keyboard.

Comment: [Someone else had Unicode minus sign problems just yesterday.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241853/numpy-gives-nan-while-reading-a-negative-number-from-a-file) I wonder if you're working from related data sources.

Comment: Somehow, you managed to include an `em-dash` in your code.  You need a minus sign, also known as `hyphen`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you maybe copy/pasted your code from somewhere. That is not a valid negative sign in Python. Use the key next to the 0 on your keyboard.

You can check to see if you are using the correct value.

Enter in this for the proper hyphen:

```
a = ord('-')
```

And this for yours:

```
b = ord('−')
```

and output them to see the difference.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you have an en dash or an em dash from Microsoft Word.

Answer (score 2):

I copied and pasted part of your code into python:

```
c = '−5'

print(ord(c[0]))
print(ord('-'))
```

Gives:

```
8722
45
```